# rails prawn draw a line inside table or cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn

I have a table made up of many cells, and in one cell i want to draw a horizontal line, and if i try horizontal_line it shows table document unsupported type.

and i'm using prawn ruby gem

Ex

```
cell_1 = make_cell(:content => "this row content comes directly ", height: 62.5.mm, size: 6)
cell_2 = make_cell(:content => "this row content comes directly ", height: 62.5.mm, size: 6)
cell_3 = make_cell(:content => "this row content comes directly ", height: 62.5.mm, size: 6)
t = make_table([[cell_1],[cell2], [cell3])
t.draw
```

i tried like using

```
cell4 = horizontal_rule(some values)
```

make_table shows error unrecognized table content, when i add cell4 to it.

How do i draw line inside the table or make cell

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing months a go but finally I decided to forget using prawn cause it make every thing hard! If you have enough time to use another pdf generator I recommend you to use Wicked_PDF gem ([here](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)) and draw your table with simple **html** and **css**. **Wicked pdf** is faster easier and makes you be more creative.

Comment: I used wicked_pdf long time until i had to produce a bigger pdf. With prawn you have to spend one day with theyr manual https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn#manual. You have to dig in a other world: PDF. Then, ist much easier, much faster and much more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the Prawn::Table::Cell class. Here's how I did it:

```
class RedTriangleCell < Prawn::Table::Cell
  def natural_content_width
    0
  end

  def natural_content_height
    0
  end

  def draw_content
    color = @pdf.fill_color
    @pdf.fill_color("e93131")
    @pdf.fill_polygon([-5,2], [-1,8], [3,2])
    @pdf.fill_color(color)
  end
end
```

You can drop an instance of this as the cell content and it will render whatever you have in `draw_content`.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff! draw_content returns `Pdf::Core::Stream`. But, how to bring this in into the cell? `make_cell(content: <.draw_content>)` didnt work